# Espresso RecyclerView in SwipeRefreshLayout blocks test

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have RecyclerView

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_swiperefreshlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/events_dashboard_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Witch is in fragment in Viewpager.
I'm using volley for server calls with custom IdleResurs.

I want to open the drawer:

```
openDrawer(R.id.drawer_layout);
isOpen();
```

But the test hangs with error:

```
Could not launch intent Intent within 45 seconds
```

If I manually scroll the RecycleView or change the visible page in the adapter the test continues and the drawer gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

The loading indicator of the SwipeRefreshLayout might be shown and thus blocking the UI because it is animating. A quick fix to avoid the layout to show the animation is to use something like this instead:

```
class TestableSwipeRefreshLayout : SwipeRefreshLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    companion object {

        var isTestRunning = false

    }

    override fun setRefreshing(refreshing: Boolean) {
        if (!isTestRunning) {
            super.setRefreshing(refreshing)
        }
    }

}
```